# How can I update a global variable in Cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, graphql, cypress

I want to use a Global variable inside my Cypress test file but its value isn't changing as expected despite adding waits.

```
const builder = {
  stepsArr: []
};
describe('my test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept('/graphql', (req) => {
      req.continue((res) => {
        if (res.body.data?.steps) {
          builder.stepsArr = res.body.data.steps.steps;
          console.log({ stepsArr: builder.stepsArr }); // logs correctly!
        }
      });
    }).as('graphqlRequest');
  });
  it.only('should check global var', () => {
    cy.waitFor('steps');
    cy.wrap({ getStepByTitle: pathwayBuilder.getStepByTitle })
      .invoke('getStepByTitle',
        'some title',
        builder.stepsArr // always empty array!
      )
      .then((stepObj) => {
        cy.log(stepObj);
      });
  });
});
```

The order of execution is correct but the value of Global variable isn't updating. Its showing empty array when I invoke my function despite retrying for like 100 times. What could be wrong?

`cy.waitFor('steps');` is from a command in `support/commands.js` file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('waitFor', operationName => {
  cy.wait('@graphqlRequest').then(({ request }) => {
    if (request.body.operationName !== operationName) {
      cy.log('Waiting for:', operationName)
      return cy.waitFor(operationName)
    }
    return null
  })
})
```

The function just logs the parameters on console

```
exports.pathwayBuilder = {
    getStepByTitle: (title, steps) => {
        console.log("Search", title);
        console.log("Steps", steps); // empty!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `.invoke()` args are wrong, see this example [invoke() - functions with arguments](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Function-with-Arguments)

```js
const fn = (a, b, c) => {
  return a + b + c
}

cy.wrap({ sum: fn })
  .invoke('sum', 2, 4, 6)
  .should('be.gt', 10) // true
  .and('be.lt', 20) // true
```

...the function takes three arguments and they are passed in comma-separated.

You `getStepByTitle` accepts two arguments, but you pass in one  - an object containing the second argument

so

```js
 .invoke('getStepByTitle', {
   steps: builder.stepsArr // always empty array!
 })
```

should be

```js
 .invoke('getStepByTitle', 'aTitle', builder.stepsArr )
```

---

Some more things I found in running the test

1. `getStepByTitle()` needs to return something, otherwise `stepObj` (the result of the `.invoke()`) will be undefined
2. the `cy.wait()` does not succeed (for me) inside the custom command, but it does work if I inline the code of the custom command in the test (for ref Cypress 7.1.0)
3. the `cy.wrap({ getStepByTitle }).invoke(...` is evaluating before the `cy.wait()` finishes. Looks like some sort of optimization, Cypress is invoking when the command is added to the queue.

Substitute

```js
.then(obj => obj.getStepByTitle('some title', builder.stepsArr))`
```

for

```
.invoke('getStepByTitle', 'some title',  builder.stepsArr )
```

Comment: You're correct but this does not solve my problem. I have already tried that.

Comment: I'm also seeing an error **req.continue is not a function** - what version of Cypress are you running? I'm on v6.8.0 because of [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15901#event-4576204020)

Comment: I'm using v7.0.0 req.continue works and I can see that in the document as well: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepting-a-request

Comment: Yes, I'm just upgrading - going to v7.1.0

Comment: See my notes above - now it is working for me.